# Access VBAでAZURE SQLへEXPORT時に既存の場合エラーとなる

Tags: azure, ms-access, vba, sql-azure

Access VBAで以下の命令によりAZURE SQLへEXPORTしようとしたとき、テーブルがサーバー上に既存の場合エラーとなります。
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC データベース", "ODBC;DSN=test;UID=test;PWD=test;", acTable, "TMP_test", "T_test", False, True

サーバー側のテーブルを削除するか、上書きする方法をご存知の方、教えてください。

よろしく願いします。

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio で削除することはできるのですが、利用者にも作業できるようにVBAで削除する方法があれば、助かります。

Comment: 解決しました。
以下回答をご覧ください。

Answer (score 1):

以下の方法にて削除し、サーバーへexport後リンクインポートできました。

```vba
Set db = New ADODB.Connection
db.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
    "Data Source=******.database.windows.net,1433; " & _
    "User Id=*****@*******; Password=*******; " & _
    "Initial Catalog={DB Name};"
db.Execute "DROP TABLE テーブル名"
db.Close
Set db = Nothing

'--- 一時テーブルをサーバーへUP
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC データベース", _
    "ODBC;DSN={DB　Name};UID=******;PWD=*****;", _
    acTable, LoalTableName, ServeTableName, False, True

'--- ローカルへリンクインポート
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC データベース", _
    "ODBC;DSN={DB Name};UID=******;PWD=******;", _
    acTable, LocalTableName, ServerTableName, False, True
```

参考サイト
http://www.happy2-island.com/access/gogo03/capter00415.shtml